# Removing the duplicates from the String in java

Tags: java, string, duplicates

Remove to duplicates from the string given in java
for eg:- if my string is "cutcopypaste"
 then the output should be as "uoyase"

Input:- cutcopypaste;
Output:- uoyase;
Here, is the program i have written. What changes should i make?
But my output is coming like this:-cuttcoppyppastte

```
class Remove {
 public static String remo(String st) {
  char[] ch = st.toCharArray();
  st = "";
  String st1 = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
   for (int j = 1; j < ch.length; j++) {
    if (ch[i] == ch[j]) {
     st1 = st1 + ch[i];
    } else {
     st = st + ch[i];
    }
   }
  }
  return st;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String st1 = "cutcopypaste";
  st1 = remo(st1);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be to iterate over the char array and remember how often each char occurred. In this case we can use the wrapper type `Boolean` which gives us 3 possible states for each character: `null` = did not occur yet, `true` = did occur once, `false` = did occur more than once.

To hold these states I would use a `LinkedHashMap` as it preserves insertion order. To get the result string we simply iterate over the map's entries, filter out everything that has not the state `true` (i.e. occurred once) and concatenate to a string.

```
public class Duplicate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(remo("cutcopypaste"));
    }

    public static String remo(String st) {

        Map<Character, Boolean> occurredOnlyOnce = new LinkedHashMap<>(); //preserves insertion order

        for(char c : st.toCharArray()) {
            Boolean occurred = occurredOnlyOnce.get(c);
            if(occurred == null) {
                occurredOnlyOnce.put(c, true);
            } else if(occurred) {
                occurredOnlyOnce.put(c, false);
            }
        }

        return occurredOnlyOnce.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue())
            .map(e -> e.getKey().toString())
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach where you will convert the string to a character array like .toCharArray().

And then convert the char array to a set which will remove duplicate.

```
public static Set convertToSet(char[] charArray) { 
// Result hashset 
Set resultSet = new HashSet(); 
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) { 
resultSet.add(newCharacter(charArray[i])); 
} 
// Return result 
return resultSet; 
}
```

Comment: But i want no instance of the repetition. Meaning if c occurred twice it should not print the letter c.

Comment: That is why i am moving the elements of char array to a set of character. And set in java doesn't allow duplicate values. What is the problem here

Answer (score 0):

If an order does not matter for you then you can try this piece of code:

```
 List<Character> result = input
            .chars()
            .mapToObj(el -> (char) el)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(el -> el.getValue() == 1L)
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```